# Cypress code coverage with nyc "all" option does not report source code as "uncovered"

Tags: vue.js, code-coverage, cypress, instrumentation, nyc

My code coverage report shows 100% covered source code. However, I would expect less because there is only one test file (`FooPage.spec.js`) covering one (`FooPage.vue`) of two components. The second component (`BarPage.spec.js`) is shown in the report but not considered in the coverage metrics. I would have expected to see `BarPage.ts` reported as red with 0/4 statements covered (instead of 0/0).

[image: unexpected code coverage]

I guess, the instrumentation with `nyc` does not work as expected with the `all` option.

See https://github.com/toaditoad/code-coverage-mwe for a reproducible example.

See https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1415 with same question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Readme of my updated working example for a (not so nice) workaround to add all source files as additional entries in Cypress' webpack preprocessor: https://github.com/toaditoad/code-coverage-mwe

This only works for Cypress 6.x but raised as request for Cypress 7.x which does not support the webpack preprocessor: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17230